# Transactions and behaviour of snapshotChanges in Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using `Firebase` and subscribe to [snapshotChanges](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges) to retrieve an update whenever my realtime database is being updated.

`Service A` is subscribing to the observer. `Service B` writes 100 items to the realtime database as follows:

```
const objs = {'fooA': valueA, 'fooB': valueB, ... };
const dbRef = firebase.database().ref(`projects/${project}`);
return dbRef.transaction((transaction) => {
  return objs;
}, undefined, false);
```

As you can see `objs` might contain several hundred items. Once the transaction is executed, I receive an update in `Service A` for every single item that the other services added to the database.

Since I used a transaction I was hoping that I also only receive 1 single callback, instead of 100's. Currently, I help myself out with a delay timer but I would prefer to avoid that.

```
this.observer$ = this.db.list(`projects/${project}/`).snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(auditTime(200))
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

**Output with`auditItem`:**

```
(100) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
...
```

**Output without `auditItem`:**

```
(0) []
(1) [{…}]
> 0:{payload: DataSnapshot, type: 'value'...
(2) [{…}, {…}]
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
...
```

Any ideas what the API offers for me?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the minimal, **complete**/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce the problem. Specifically, show what database path you're listening to, and how you're dealing with the data you receive (logging it is preferred, if you can reproduce the problem that way).

Comment: Thanks for your input! It is indeed not a "copy, paste and run" example, but doesn't the first code block contain everything? E.g. `the database path`? Any help is appreciated and I will update my question. Thanks!

Comment: Your first code block shows how you run a transaction that *writes* to the data. I'm asking to see the minimal-but-complete observer where you have problems.

Comment: Understood, I added the full observer code

Comment: Hmm...  since you're using a transaction, you should only be seeing one value event on the observer for each transaction as far as I can see. Did you try if you get the same problem without AngularFire? You could also check the Web Socket traffic in the Network tab of your browser, as you should only get a single frame (depending a bit on the number of items). If none of this explains, can you reproduce in a site like jsbin? I might also give that a try myself tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I will check it out and update my question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you're describing with the regular JavaScript SDK. Using two app instances in a single jsbin to simulate the two clients:

```
var primary = firebase.initializeApp(CONFIG);
var secondary = firebase.initializeApp(CONFIG, "secondary");

var ref = primary.database().ref("68615288");
var objs = {};
for (var i=0; i < 100; i++) objs["key_"+i] = "hello";

ref.transaction(function(transaction) {
  return objs;
}, undefined, false);

secondary.database().ref("68615288").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Listener got a snapshot with "+snapshot.numChildren()+" child nodes");
});
```

When I ran this on an empty node, the output I got was:

> "Listener got a snapshot with 0 child nodes"
>
> "Listener got a snapshot with 100 child nodes"

This is the expected behavior, as the listener first gets the empty node, and then got the node with 100 children from the transaction.

https://jsbin.com/wuhuyih/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Hey Frank, sorry for the delay. I couldn't get over it why it did work in my hello-world example but not in my app. And I finally understand what happened on my side. It seems to me this is caused by a mistake on my end with Angular and the way how I subscribe to the events. I accidentally registered too many subscribers without unsubscribing. In the end, I had a lot of zombie subscribers. After cleaning up that part I can confirm now works as you described. Thanks so much again for confirming this is the right behavior.